# Проверка наличия  в HTML документе.

Tags: ajax, html, javascript

Здравствуйте товарищи! С наступающим вас! Такая есть задача, начну с начала :

Есть самый обыкновенный **HTML** документ, в котором содержатся две метки :

```
<script>code...</script>
```

Пишется сценарий, который будет без перезагрузки страницы, показывать нужную заместо той, которую видим(нафигация через **Ajax**). У каждой страницы будет имя, **javascript** код, и тело страницы. Собственно вопрос : как отследить, если ли уже в **HTML** документе метка

```
<script>code...</script>
```

их может быть несколько и содержать они могут разный код. Однако, если человек несколько раз загрузит одну и ту же страницу, то один и тот же код будет добавлен между

```
<head>...</head>
```

а делать этого не нужно. Возможно ли отследить такое? Можно ли их как - то пронумеровать, занести в какой - нибудь массив для отслеживания?

Comment: странная у вас идея - использовать метки. я бы ajax навигацию явно по другому бы разрабатывал

Comment: Возможно, мы не так друг друга поняли, под метками я подразумевал понятие tag(HTML tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я всё правильно понял. Присвоить уникальный id, а именно:

```
<script id="foo">
```

А во время загрузки очередной страницы, проверять наличие и...

```
.remove()
```

Comment: Да, вы всё правильно поняли. Но разрешает ли стандарт добавлять к <script> св - во id?

Comment: Для меня преимуществом является в первую очередь валидность, которая, к сожалению, иногда расходится со стандартами W3C.

Если пропахших нафталином (к примеру, IE6) нормально реагирует, то я считаю, что это валидное решение. К примеру, использования плагинов JQuery tooltip или FancyBox, подразумевает размещение в атрибутах alt и title верстки (html-сущностей), и ничего.

Что касается присвоения id  тегу <script>, то мне приходилось прибегать к подобному, когда использовал CMS-ки с модулями, напачканных JS.

Comment: Кстати, 

[Giving the script tag an ID][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741441/giving-the-script-tag-an-id

Comment: Ну чтож, спасибо!